# How can I start row edit mode on a new form control in a primeng table?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeng table that takes data from a form array.

I want to start row edit mode on a new form control of that form array programmatically.

I've been trying using this function but I do not know how to use it properly:

table.initRowEdit();

```
public addNewElement(): void {
    const newFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      code: new FormControl(null),
      type: new FormControl(null),
    });
    this.formArray.insert(0, newFormGroup);
    this.table.initRowEdit(this.formArray.controls[0]);
  }
```

If I click in the template button annotated with: *pInitEditableRow* it works as expected. But I want to add a new row and start editing it without having to click in any button.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I've found the solution...

```
public addNewElement(): void {
const newFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  code: new FormControl(null),
  type: new FormControl(null),
});
this.formArray.insert(0, newFormGroup);
this.table.initRowEdit(this.formArray.controls[0].value);
```

}